# What's the fastest Request or Http module in Node.JS npm packages

Tags: node.js, http, npm, request, benchmarking

I am building a software and carrying about performance, I need to consume some web services (only get requests). I googled about it but hasn't found something relevant. So, I am looking for a way to benchmark this two modules. Do you know a good benchmark tool for doing this? Or maybe a ready to use report on that subject?

I know that Request is made on top of http, but this doesn't currently mean that it can perform better or worse.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch ?

It seems to be faster than core http & request for me ...